# Windows 10 randomly drops wifi and wired network connection for no reason

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, internet-connection

I have a htpc which runs windows 10 pro (64 bit). It has a wired and a wireless connection. Everything works fine, except for the internet connection. Seemingly without any reason, when browsing the internet, the connection will drop. Then minutes later (sometimes longer), it'll be working again.

I've been troubleshooting this for half a year now, so let me explain what I've found so far:

- Other devices still have access to the internet on the same network when the connection drops for the htpc. So it's not the network.
- I've had Ubuntu and Macos run on the same machine (the htpc), without *ever* experiencing these issues. No connection drops ever. So it's not the hardware.
- I've not experienced these issues with the htpc when attempting to access the local network, only for the internet (so youtube.com or whatever)

The htpc is running on a [Asus Z170I Pro Gaming](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Z170I-PRO-GAMING/). I'm not using a separate network card, just what's on the motherboard. Windows has been updated to the latest version and I've updated to the latest Intel I219-V drivers (the networking chip on this motherboard). The problems still persist. Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: If you setup a continuously ping to google 8.8.8.8 for instance, what does it say when the connection is lost? Timed out, Destination unreachable, General failure or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying basically everything, I fixed it by manually setting the gateway and dns to the ip address of my router (hardware settings on windows machine) and forcibly turning off dhcp (also on my windows machine).

It should have gotten all this right by itself (as all the other machines on my network do), but since this is a microsoft product it makes sense that it doesn't. I'm happy that this resolved it. Will begrudgingly keep on using this sorry excuse for an OS until something better comes along.

Answer (score 0):

I've had some success with finding an older version of the NIC driver and try it.
My own laptop when upgraded would connect/disconnect from the internet randomly until I replaced the new Windows 10 supplied driver with the 6 year old original Dell approved version for Windows 7.